# How to get the upper bound of $\sup_{z\in\partial{B_0}}\exp\left[-\frac{d(z,y)^2}{C}\right]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

How to estimate the maximal of the following formula:

$$\sup_{z\in\partial{B_0}}\exp\left[-\frac{d(z,y)^2}{C}\right]\leq ?$$

where $B_0:=B(x_0, R)$ and $z, y\in B(x_0, R)$ and $C$ is some constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $C>0$ (which I assume is the case) the function

$$
\exp{\left (-\frac{d^2}{C} \right)}
$$

is a decreasing function of $d^2$. Hence its supremum is the infimum of $d^2$, which is

$$
L^2:=\left [ \inf_{z\in \partial B_0} d(z,y) \right ]^2
$$

Hence $L$ is equal to the distance of $y$ from the surface of the sfere of radius $R$.

Ultimately

$$\sup_{z\in\partial{B_0}}\exp\left[-\frac{d(z,y)^2}{C}\right]\leq  \exp{\left (-\frac{L^2}{C} \right)} \le 1
$$

Comment: But why the answer is $L^2=R^2$? I do not think the infimum of $d^2$ is $R^2$.

Comment: In fact it is not. As it is stated $y$ could belong to the boundary in which case the sup is 1.